# Tikz figure mysteriously overlapping text above - in some cases only

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

One figure (two TikZ-figures next to each other, using `subfigure`) is overlapping the text above with no obvious reason. When adding an additional one-word paragraph ("text"), the problem does not occur. Instead, the figure is too close to the page number (see images attached).

```
\documentclass[parskip=half, a4paper, titlepage=firstiscover]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{flafter} 
\usepackage[section]{placeins}

\usepackage[pass]{geometry}

\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all, group-digits=integer, range-phrase = { bis }}
\AtBeginDocument{\sisetup{detect-all}}%{\sisetup{math-rm=\mathrm, text-rm=\rmfamily}}
\DeclareSIUnit{\year}{a}
\DeclareSIUnit{\euro}{\mbox{EUR}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\SendSettingsToPgf
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize[up to date check=diff]

\begin{document}
\blindtext[3]

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \input{mwe_fig.tex}
            \caption{Caption 1}
            \label{fig:example1}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \input{mwe_fig.tex}
            \caption{Caption 2}
            \label{fig:example2}
        \end{subfigure} 
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{fig:example}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The figures have been created with `matlab2tikz` and their `width` and `height` is set relative to `\linewidth` (see below).

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.594\linewidth,
height=0.6\linewidth,
at={(0\linewidth,0\linewidth)},
scale only axis,
point meta min=140,
point meta max=164.662536165299,
xmin=0,
xmax=100,
tick align=outside,
xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xlabel={Taxis},
ymin=0,
ymax=200,
ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ylabel={CS-PKW},
zmin=0,
zmax=500,
zlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
zlabel={Verlust in \si[per-mode=symbol]{\kilo\euro\per\year}},
view={-37.5}{30},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
axis z line*=left,
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
zmajorgrids
]

\addplot3[%
surf,
shader=flat corner, draw=black, z buffer=sort, colormap={mymap}{[1pt] rgb(0pt)=(0,0.180392,0.313726); rgb(1pt)=(0.0112418,0.191895,0.325752)}, mesh/rows=11]
table[row sep=crcr, point meta=\thisrow{c}] {%
%
x   y   z   c\\
0   0   164.662536165299    164.662536165299\\
0   10  169.722738787299    169.722738787299\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

[image: Figure overlapping text]

[image: Figure not overlapping but too close to the page number]

Do you have some advice? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. You could put some `\vspace` in the float before the input.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I now edited the question. Also thank you for the advice to use `\vspace`. But I am wondering how - in general - something like this can happen and assume that I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: We only see the first part of your tikz-file. Maybe the height is set to something smaller than the actual result. So TeX doesn't know the figure is actually bigger when it typesets your file, because someone lies about the size.

Comment: Still can't use you MWE for experiments.  Can you simplify things and still get the problem?

Comment: Sorry! Now everything should work - unfortunately, the problem does not reproduce in the MWE... In fact, in the meantime I made minor changes somewhere else in the document (text only) and the problem no longer occurs... for now.

Comment: Could you maybe explain what changes you've made? I'm having the same issue with parts of my subfigures overlapping with text as imaged above...